# Inconsistency in explicit call to "constructor" and destructor

Tags: c++, raii

The creation of an object involves: a) obtaining memory (on stack or heap, `operator new` handles the latter); b) initializing it (calling a constructor). Likely the destruction.

If we want to skip a) in the creation, that is, to construct an object in the memory we have already obtained, we use placement `new`.

If we want to destroy an object without releasing the memory, we call the destructor explicitly.

BUT, the constructor and the destructor are a pair of functions, and `new` and `delete` are a pair of operators.

So, why isn't the pair of placement `new` and "placement `delete`" (you can imagine), or the pair of explicit call to constructor and destructor used? And what's the intention of this inconsistency?

Comment: You don't need to use `new` (placement or not) to "obtain memory" for an object. Defining an object as a simple variable is enough.

Comment: placement `new` does not allocate memory, thats not an inconsistency, but just what it is supposed to do. It could have a different name, but keywords are rather "expensive"

Comment: It's actually a deeper inconsistency than that. We can define our versions of operator new that use the placement syntax. But there is no corresponding way to call the appropriate operator delete.